# My ASP.NET MVC project is not retrieving my SQL Server Express values

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I am currently having problem retrieving values from my SQL Server database that I have specified in my `web.config` file, Basically I have created a class library project which has the `Employee` and `Department` classes and `IDepartmentData` interface that has the `IQueryable<Employee>` and `IQueryable<Department>`

Here is how my classes look like:

```
namespace e.Manager.Data
{
    public class Department
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; } 
    }
}

namespace e.Manager.Data
{
    [Table("Person")]
    public class Employee
    {
        public virtual int Id { set; get; }
        public virtual string Name { set; get; }
    }
}
```

and here is my iInterface:

```
namespace e.Manager.Data
{
    public interface  IDepartmentData
    {
        IQueryable<Employee> Employees { get; }
        IQueryable<Department> Departments { get; }
    }
}
```

and of course I have a reference of this project in my ASP.NET MVC web project.

Here's my class `DepartmentDb`:

```
namespace eManager.Web.Infrastructure
{
    public class DepartmentDb : DbContext, IDepartmentData
    {
       public DbSet<Employee> Employees { set; get; }
       public  DbSet<Department> Departments { set; get; }

       IQueryable<Employee> IDepartmentData.Employees
       {
            get { return Employees; }
       }

       IQueryable<Department> IDepartmentData.Departments
       {
            get { return Departments; }
       }
    }
}
```

and here is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DepartmentDb" 
         connectionString="database=sample;server=CON0389\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=SSPI" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and my table contains the relevant tables `Person` and `Department`

Here is my Index action method:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
        private DepartmentDb DbObj = new DepartmentDb();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var department= DbObj.Departments;

            return View(department);
        }
}
```

but my index doesn't retrieve the values that are within the DB is there is something wrong that I am doing here? Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Is there a connection made to the DB when you debug into your code? Does it throw an error? Does your Database register that a connection was made? do you see an error in the event viewer? We don't have nearly enough information to help you diagnose why your connection isn't working without at least an error message.  Does that user have a login and the correct user permissions in SQL server? Are "named pipes" enabled in SQL server Configuration Manager? Is

Comment: It's **really** confusing and against the *Principle of Least Surprise* to get all the `DbObj.Departments`, but then calling the variable to hold them `employees` ..... so are those **employees** - or **departments**? Either the variable name is totally confusing, or the `DbObj.Departments` returns not what its name would be suggesting .....

Comment: Hi George you right actually it was suppose to be like that departments=DbObj.Departments and it seems that it's connecting to the db but not retrieving any values

Comment: Thank you guys for your answer i have figured out what was wrong in my project, the problem was that i didn't map my object to the tables in my SQL and that's why count was returning 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your answer i have figured out what was wrong in my project, the problem was that i didn't map my object to the tables in my SQL and that's why count was returning 0.